# Ironclad Cryptography Library for Emacs Lisp?

Tags: emacs, cryptography, elisp, common-lisp, ironclad

I love the [Ironclad](http://method-combination.net/lisp/ironclad/) cryptography library for Common Lisp. Out of curiosity, has anyone implemented this library into their Emacs Lisp project?  In researching this question, I suspected there would be too much work to make it compatible with a pure Emacs Lips project, but a hybrid Elisp and CL project might also be an option for what I need to do.

Answer (score 3):

Some of the functionality of ironclad is built-in to Emacs via the `secure-hash` and `md5` functions. http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Checksum_002fHash.html has more information.

These functions are written in C. I don't know for sure, but it seems like Emacs Lisp's slow speed and small fixnums would be a real obstacle for doing this work directly in pure elisp.

Comment: I noted Emacs Lisp provides access to many features Ironclad does.  What sets Ironclad apart is the project scope, "to unify several of the cryptographic packages for Common Lisp", "providing a cryptographic toolkit similar in scope to something like OpenSSL or Crypto++" with support for several popular ciphers, digests, and MACs.  Perhaps what I should do is look at how to simply utilize Emacs Lisp for all the same functionality, but I already am familiar with Ironclad and honestly would like to see it fully mature by using it and noting areas of improvement.  Appreciate the answer, though!